# About the derivation of a composite quaternion

Tags: rotation, frame, composite, quaternions

This problem has been bothering me for several days, hence I decided to ask you for help.

I am reading the book "Quaternions and Rotation Sequence" written by Jack B. Kuipers. In section 6.4, the author derives a formula of a composite rotation quaternion. One of the steps of this derivation is difficult for me to understand.

I would like to briefly describe the derivation process as follow:

Consider a tracking problem as in [this picture](http://i256.photobucket.com/albums/hh191/kgjEhi78238a9gHw/tracking_problem_zpsb5d51abb.png).

(I am sorry I have to use links instead of posting pictures directly because this is the first time I post a question here so I am not eligible to do so yet)

In the picture, XYZ is a global, reference frame. 2 successive rotations are performed: 
The first one is a rotation about the Z axis through an angle alpha, transforming frame XYZ into a new frame x1y1z1.
The second one is a rotation about the y1 axis through an angle beta, transforming frame x1y1z1 into a new frame x2y2z2.

The goal is to find a single composite rotation quaternion which is equivalent to the two rotations above.

The author does this as follow. The first rotation can be represented by the following quaternion p:

p = cos(alpha/2) + **k***sin(alpha/2) (1)

In this formula, **k** is a standard basis vector (we have vectors **i**, **j**, **k** in R3 corresponding to the axes x, y, z respectively).

The second rotation can be represented by the following quaternion q:

q = cos(beta/2) + **j***sin(beta/2) (2)

The composite quaternion we are looking for is the product of these 2 quaternions: qp. The formula of this product is in [this picture](http://i256.photobucket.com/albums/hh191/kgjEhi78238a9gHw/qp_product_zps6f0b9e3a.png).

In order to derive this final formula, the author uses 2 assumptions about the standard basis vectors **i**, **j**, **k**, which are: **k.j** = 0 and **k** x **j** = -**i**. And this is where I dont understand.

We all know that, for a set of 3 mutually orthogonal vectors **i**, **j**, **k**, these 2 assumptions above are correct. However, vector **k** in (1) and vector **j** in (2) don't belong to the same coordinate frame. In other words, **k** in (1) corresponds to Z in frame XYZ, and **j** in (2) corresponds to y1 in x1y1z1. And these are 2 different, distinguish frames, so I think the second assumption used by the author is incorrect.

What do you think about this? Any answer would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This question is more for [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

**author uses 2 assumptions about the standard basis vectors i, j, k...**

it is not assumption! 
You not understand cross product and dot product see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

**3 mutually orthogonal vectors i, j, k**

orthogonal vectors.... What is it(definition)?
Dot_product... What is it(definition)?
Can we define orthogonal vectors via Dot_product?

You must learn a basic of Linear algebra and Complex analysis  before understand quaternion.